# Ansible SSH best practices

Tags: ansible, security

What are the best practices to be followed wrt security when it comes to SSH authentication (password less, key based, etc.) when setting up Ansible in a new environment with 1000s of machines? Which is the best method of using passwordless SSH in an enterprise environment and why?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `Key Based SSH`

Reasons

1. You can SSH multiple host machines using the same key or Different keys.
2. If you reboot your machine while playbook running it again SSH using your provided key so your ansible-playbook runs without occurring any errors.
3. Also, you get authentication using the appropriate user.

use can use **inventory.ini** file

**example**

```
[hostMachine]
ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx  ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path of your pem file

[ABCDMachine]
ABCD@xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_ssh_user=ABCD ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path of your pem file
```

**Command for run ansible-playbook**

> ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini main.yml